# How to assign the label of one column to the new one based on group maximum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have the following sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id_hour', 'Id', 'hour', 'label'])

df['Id_hour'] = ['A_1','A_2','A_3','A_4','B_1','B_2','B_3','B_4','C_1','C_2','C_3','C_4']

df['Id'] = ['A','A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
df['hour'] = ['1','2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3','4','1', '2', '3','4']
df['label'] = ['H','L', 'L', 'L', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L','H', 'H', 'L', 'L']
```

I want to get the maximum number of the appearance of the label column per Id. Then assign that label (which appears maximum times)  to all raws of that specific Id, in a new column name called *assigned_label*.
If there is no single local maximum (e.g. if a label appears equally per Id), I want to assign a new label 'R' to all rows of this Id of *assigned_label* column.
The output result should look like below

```
df['assigned_label'] = ['L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'H', 'H', 'H','H','R','R', 'R', 'R']
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df['assigned_label'] = df.groupby('Id')['label']\
                         .transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0] if len(x.mode()) == 1 else 'R')
```

Output:

```
   Id_hour Id hour label assigned_label
0      A_1  A    1     H              L
1      A_2  A    2     L              L
2      A_3  A    3     L              L
3      A_4  A    4     L              L
4      B_1  B    1     H              H
5      B_2  B    2     H              H
6      B_3  B    3     H              H
7      B_4  B    4     L              H
8      C_1  C    1     H              R
9      C_2  C    2     H              R
10     C_3  C    3     L              R
11     C_4  C    4     L              R
​
```

Comment: This is great! Would you please explain what does x.mode() do? And where is the per group maximum appearance label selection happens? I asked this because I would like to adapt your code based on my other conditions. Thanks.

Comment: [pd.Series.mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas-series-mode) Note, it returns a Series, hence the `[0]` to get the first/only value else, if more than two modes in a dataset, then return 'R'.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
df.groupby('Id')['label'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
```

O/P:

```
   Id_hour Id hour label assigned_label
0      A_1  A    1     H              L
1      A_2  A    2     L              L
2      A_3  A    3     L              L
3      A_4  A    4     L              L
4      B_1  B    1     H              H
5      B_2  B    2     H              H
6      B_3  B    3     H              H
7      B_4  B    4     L              H
8      C_1  C    1     H              L
9      C_2  C    2     H              L
10     C_3  C    3     L              L
11     C_4  C    4     L              L
```

Note: If multiple values equal the maximum, the first row label with that value is returned instead of `R`

Comment: Thanks, but your solution solves only the max appearance value but not on labeling R. When multiple levels have the same number of appearance a new label R should be assigned.

Comment: @ewalel - I agree with you. that's why I put note in my post :)